# JSTL forEach performance

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I was hoping somebody could help me understand why there is a performance difference between the following two JSTL forEach.

Both only runs 5 times based on the `System.out` but difference between the time to serve the page is **HUGE** as you increment the `begin` to bigger numbers in ***Code A*** the page takes noticeably longer and longer, when you get to 190000000 it will seem to never end.

When running ***Code A*** the CPU spikes to 100 and the memory takes a big hit.

***Code A***

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="${190000000}" end="${ 190000000 +5}" >
    <% System.out.println("i="  ); %>
    <td>${i+currentPage}</td>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have a workaround which is to use the following where `currentPage` is actually the number `190000000` so keeping my `begin` and `end` low keeps the loop performant.

***Code B***

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="${0}" end="${ 0+5}" >
    <td>${i+currentPage}</td>
 </c:forEach>
```

My JSTL version is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And I am running tomcat 6 and also tested with same issue in tomcat8

Comment: there is no problem, you should just use `foreach` properly. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

Comment: That doesn't help at all, did you read the question? , the documentation does not specify any bounds for `begin` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html `begin =` "If items not specified: Iteration begins with index set at the value specified."

Comment: @destroy-everything I tried the same case with for each loop in java file,but all was well,is it something that you face,specific to jsp usage?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal Yes, the JSP project was simplified down to basically what is in this post and still got the problem, did you use JSTL ? could you try it in a JSP? Thanks!

Comment: @destroy-everything I will try it out.Did you try out using some performance analysis tool such as visualVM?

Comment: I did , but to be honest I couldn't see what was wrong except that it was using way more memory than expected as soon as the loop runs.